# Increasing Parallellism in Spark Executor without increasing Cores

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a Spark-Kafka Streaming job with 4 executors(1 core each). And the kafka source topic had 50 partitions.

In the foreachpartition of the streaming java program, i am connecting to oracle and doing some work. Apache DBCP2 is  being used for connection pool.

Spark-streaming program is making 4 connections to database- may be 1 for each executor. But, My Expectation is -  since there are 50 partitions, there should be 50 threads running and 50 database connections exist.

How do i increase the parallelism without increasing the number of cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expectations are wrong. One core is one available thread in Spark nomenclature and one partition that can be processed at the time.

4 "cores" -> 4 threads -> 4 partitions processed concurently.

Comment: Does that mean that i can see max of 4 database connections at  a time?

Answer (score 1):

In spark executor, each core processes partitions one by one(one at a time). As you have 4 executors and each has only 1 core, that means you can only process 4 partitions concurrently at a time. So, if your Kafka has 50 partitions, your spark cluster need to run 13 rounds(4 partitions each round, 50 / 4 = 12.5) to finish a batch job. That is also why you can only see 4 connections to database.